# Android UI testing: "adb shell uiautomator" throws error, "uiautomator" in "adb shell" works

Tags: android, shell, command-line, adb, android-uiautomator

I would like to compile and run Android UI black-box tests using only command-line tools on Windows. I wrote an `UiAutomatorTestCase`, built it, and uploaded it into `/data/local/tmp/`. I verified that the `jar` file was copied into the latter directory.

If I type

```
adb shell
```

and then type

```
uiautomator runtest MyTest.jar –c com.example.MyTest
```

at the adb shell prompt, the test runs successfully. So far so good.

The problem is if I combine these two steps and type

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest MyTest.jar –c com.example.MyTest
```

then I get the following error:

```
Error: /data/local/tmp/ľc does not exist
```

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html), this should work. The error is the same on Windows 7 Pro 32-bit HUN and on Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit ENG. The device is a Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini (GT-I8190), running Android 4.1.2 (API level 16).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suppose,

`adb shell
 $ <command>` is same as `adb shell <command>`. I've never encountered any discrepancy in this regards.

Please try `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`

Please also try `adb -s <device_id> shell <command>` you can find `<device_id>` from `adb devices`

Can you also please let us know what is the output of `adb version`?

Comment: Thanks, Anvesh. I used the latest SDK from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html Interestingly, the problem mysteriously disappeared after a while, on both dev PCs. I don't know what happened - after using the above two-step approach for a few days, I tried the one-liner again, and it worked. During these days, I did kill-server/start-server once, restarted the test devices and the dev PCs multiple times etc. I can't tell which one of these solved the problem.

Comment: Happy that your issue got resolved.. most probably it would be an SDK issue.. Can you please mark this question solved ?

Comment: OK. I guess the kill-server and start-server commands solved the problem.